# How to clear cache only for users's field?

Tags: 7, users, entities, caching

I have some cache issues on website when I run some process. I'm looking for a way for clear cache only for user's fields from a custom module. K dn't want clear all cache for save performances.

I read the documentation, but I didn't find any example for clear only user's fields cache.

Any help me?

How can I do that with the `clear_cache_all` function ? (which parameters?)

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to delete the DB entries yourself

Comment: D7's cache layer isn't too smart (compared to 8 anyway), if you manage to get hold of the key for a very specific user field cache item you can only use it to clear that item. So if the same value happens to have been used in another cached whatever, e.g. in the results of a view, clearing that single cache item won't touch the view and the content will be out of sync. Perhaps if you edit the question and explain the scenario a bit more clearly it'll be easier to advise what options you have